Операторы сравнения в css
Я сейчас изучаю media, вот у меня в курсе написано:
   @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

Означает:

на экранах, ширина которых меньше или равна 320px, картинки будут иметь ширину 100%.

Но я не пойму одного, знак меньше или равно это знак - :?
Тогда как написать больше или равно? Кто знает где найти полный список операторов сравнения в css?

«меньше или равно» это max-, «больше или равно» это min-

@andreymal спасибо, просто не логично как то

Видно у тебя своя "логика"... :)

где найти полный список операторов сравнения в css? почитать учебник по CSS... Или осилить документацию...

Обновите курс, так уже никто не пишет

Настоятельно рекомендую вам сменить курс по CSS, так как он научит вас только устаревшим практикам.
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

Так уже никто не пишет
@media (width <= 320px) {
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}


Тогда как написать больше или равно?

@media (width >= 320px) {
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

Можно даже объединить:
@media (320px <= width <= 780px) { 
   /*   */
}

Почему ваш курс учит вас устаревшему CSS?
Предположим, вы верстаете страницу в три блока колонками и ваш резиновый дизайн предусматривает отображение в две колонки или одну колонку в зависимости от размера дисплея.
В вашем курсе будет написано примерно так:
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);  
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;  
  }
}

Один и тот же селектор .container используется 3 раза, еще этот мазолящий глаз max-width. На современном CSS лучше написать так:
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols-number,3),1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  @media (width < 800px) {
    --cols-number: 2;
  }
  @media (width < 400px) {
    --cols-number: 1;
  }
}

Один селектор, одно свойство, чистые media-запросы.
Если вы путаетесь в переменных CSS, то будет хорошей привычкой их объявлять заранее:
/* В самом верху CSS */
& {
  --cols-number: 3;
}

В верхнем уровне & {  } означает почти тоже самое, что и :root {  }.

 Есть маленькая тонкость - у & { } меньше специфичность, но вам пока этим можно не забивать голову.

Кстати, для переменных можно объявить строгий тип:
@property --cols-number {
  syntax: '<integer>';
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 3; 
}

UPD
Собрал список годных материалов по CSS.
Не знаю, понадобится ли кому-нибудь, собирал получается для себя.
Пожалуй, оставлю тут, чтобы не потерялось.

MDN - Бывали времена, когда я сказал, что одного сайта MDN достаточно, чтобы освоить все стороны web-разработки. Но время идёт, web развивается, а авторы MDN чуток подустали. В один прекрасный момент сделали циркумцизио. Новый годный контент дают читать за подписку. А так материала накопилось много. Всё, что было накоплено за годы работы, на сайте осталось. Можно пользоваться как справочником.
Web.dev - Портал для web-разработчиков. В основном информация ориентирована на начинающих. Но и опытные web-мастера могут найти что-нибудь новое в Блоге. Есть пошаговый учебник. Последние новшества в бОльшей части там отсутствуют, но и устаревшим практикам не научит. Так что учебник там вполне годный, современный и бесплатный.
WHATWG - рабочая группа по разработке HTML. У них есть свой сайт, на котором почитать особо нечего. А вот их github очень даже живой.
WPT - Unit-тесты для web-технологий. По CSS там конечно тестов маловато, в основном тестируются API, которые используют из JavaScript. Проект живой, ежедневные обновления. Сюда можно ходить подсматривать, как использовать те или иные фичи, на которых не смогли найти толковую документацию.
WICG - сообщество любителей обсудить web-технологии. Многие из авторов  участвуют в W3C. Рассуждают о старых и новых фичах, о том, что есть хорошо, что - плохо. Участвуют в формировании черновиков стандартов. Народу туда заходит не много, но те, кто заходят - все ребята знаковые, как минимум с 20+ летним опытом.
CSSWG - рабочая группа по CSS. В отличии от HTML, у CSS сообщество весьма активное. Это, кстати, видно по результатам их деятельности - CSS разрастается как грибница после дождя. Контингент авторов - с опытом 10+ лет минимум. Здесь можно почитать обсуждения. Предлагают и новые идеи. Именно тут рождаются новые фичи в Web-технологиях.
Черновики стандартов CSS - это подраздел сайта CSSWG (см. выше). Но ссылку выделил отдельно. Тут можно почитать результаты творчества CSSWG.
Can I Use - Сайт ведёт активный мониторинг поддержки фичей в различных версиях браузеров. Тут следует смотреть стоит ли использовать ту или иную фичу сегодня, или до её использования следует немного подождать? Уровень поддержки каждой фичи замеряется в процентном соотношении пользователей браузеров, которые поддерживают фичу к общему количеству пользователей всех браузеров. Весьма залипательные метрики. Новичкам будет также полезно смотреть в список всех фич - справочной информации там нет, но список фич полный. Если видите тут что-либо в первый раз в жизни, то сразу следует погуглить фичу.
СSS-tricks - блог со статьями про CSS от разных разработчиков. Проект DigitalOcean. Многие новости про CSS видят свет впервые именно тут.
Developer.Chrome.com - сайт разработчиков браузера Chrome. Новости из этого блога обязательны к прочтению.
Webkit - сайт разработчиков самого популярного браузерного движка. В блоге в последнее время инфа появляется редко, но если что-то тут пишут, это будет по-любому что-то важное.
Codepen - сервис для обкатывания web-идей. Простой редактор HTML+CSS+JS с моментальным предпросмотром. Но сам сайт интересен не столько как редактор, сколько своей социальной составляющей. Лучшая подборка нестандартных супер-идей. Регулярно проводятся различные челенжы, за счет чего постоянно обновляются тренды. Здесь можно потратить много часов. Также сюда можно заходить за вдохновением в периоды депрессивной фазы СДВГ. Если всё достало, то эти мини-демошки помогут завести мозг на работу.


Зачем использовать новый CSS, если можно использовать старый CSS и получить более хорошую совместимость с браузерами?

@andreymal почти на все фичи есть полифилы. На сколько браузер должен быть старым? IE6 вроде не актуален, современные браузеры требуют обновляться сами собой.

А это всё не имеет никакого значения. Если новая фича не имеет преимуществ перед старой фичей и при этом старую фичу никто не планирует убирать — зачем использовать новую фичу?

@andreymal  с этой фичей код становится а) короче, б) понятнее. Сама фича входит в Baseline 2023. Если у вас нет машины времени и вы не летаете в прошлое, то при программировании новых проектов стоит концентрировать внимание на будущих версиях браузеров, чем на версиях браузерах, например, не поддерживающих TLS1.3, которые ругаются на все сервисы https, из-за того, что в них не обновлены сертификаты корневых CA. Да и люди, сидящие на ХР привыкли к тому, что сайты у них работают коряво... их такое поведение не удивляет.

«короче» — всего на два символа, несущественно; «понятнее» — min и max тоже вполне понятны; «Baseline 2023» — вот о чём я и говорю, все остальные браузеры в пролёте; «концентрировать внимание на будущих версиях браузеров» — это ваше субъективное мнение, не имеющее под собой никаких объективных причин; «TLS1.3» — ну лол, в РФ он уже блокируется из-за ECH; «не обновлены сертификаты» — их вполне можно обновить, я раздавал инструкции народу ещё в 2020 году. В общем, ни одного существенного аргумента переходить на новый CSS вы не привели

@andreymal какие браузеры в пролете? Приведите примеры. Я, для примера, тоже фанат NetSurf. Но, когда я использую NetSurf, я не ожидаю от него плавных анимаций CSS, прекрасно понимаю для чего предназначен этот браузер, там нет полной поддержки flex, и тем более grid. У меня есть знакомые пользователи Android 4. Это интересный тип людей,  такие люди получают информацию из телевизора. Не думаю, что такие люди даже случайно попадут на современные сайты. С вами согласен в том, что надо знать все возможные способы верстки, в том числе без flex и grid. Но новые проекты верстать на таблицах моветон

«Приведите примеры» — уверен, вы и сами способны открыть caniuse.com (тем более «Baseline 2023» вы наверняка именно оттуда и взяли). Ну и про NetSurf тоже: если я могу получить поддержку NetSurf ценой всего двух дополнительных символов в коде — почему бы и нет, собственно?

@DiD сидящие на ХР привыкли, когда я использую NetSurf, я не ожидаю от него плавных анимаций CSS, там нет flex/grid, не летаете в прошлое  как то раз прошлое прилетело в меня...))) плашка оперативки сгорела. да так удачно, что стёрла биос на основном ПК. ради поиска оного пришлось доставать из широких... антресолей нетбук с winXP на борту. куда из-за сертов пришлось накатить FF 52.9 ESR поддерживающий CSS3 GRID :3 и да, "поддержка" не про плавность, а про хоть какую-то "запускаемость". с baseline 23 в @media, она отправится лесом, а вместе с ней и пользователи...

Погрепал у себя access.log за ноябрь и даже нашёл реального (зарегистрированного и активного) пользователя с Android 4.4 и Chrome 81. Ещё вспомнил, что ещё один реальный пользователь уже несколько лет докучает меня баг-репортами о том, что что-то не работает в его древнем Firefox 56, и отвечает отказом на любые предложения обновиться. Ну и в целом набирается несколько процентов относительно живых юзеров с древними хромами (85, 90, 100, 103). Не знаю, что мешает им обновиться и почему ваше утверждение «современные браузеры требуют обновляться сами собой» не работает, но вот такие юзеры есть

@puffleeck, плашка оперативки сгорела. да так удачно, что стёрла биос на основном ПК. - я это и имел в виду. Когда люди используют WinXP для серфинга, - у них явно есть проблемы куда большего масштаба, чем поддержка CSS. Вы же явно не анекдоты серфили в этот момент. В конце концов, сайт хоть как-то отображается же. Прочитать информацию возможно. На худой конец есть lynx или elinks - они точно работают, даже гуглить можно.

@DiD, хоть как-то отображается же. ровно потому что там не позволяли себе мышления хочу фичи из свежайшего baseline, тех у кого-то что то не работает - шлём обновляться. потому что: у них явно есть проблемы куда большего масштаба. представьте что звоните в скорую а на том конце: чтоб получить помощь, установите наше приложение совместимое только с последними версиями IOS\android На худой конец есть... живительной флешки у него под рукой может не быть, что неизбежно приводит к работает не трогай в т.ч. и в установке знакомого софта, ибо риск подцепить амиго никуда не делся.

@puffleeck так речь же идет о медиа-запросах, которые по сути нужны не для "ровности" отображения, а для отображения на мобильных дисплеях разных размеров. В вашем случае их наличие никак негативно влиять не могут. Я не в курсе как давно у вас это было, но последние года 4 вы не смогли бы загуглить проблему - Google никак отображается на WinXP во всех версиях Opera, Firefox и Chrome - ни ровно, ни криво - вообще никак

@andreymal Погрепал у себя access.log за ноябрь и даже нашёл реального (зарегистрированного и активного) пользователя с Android 4.4 и Chrome 81. Ну вы же понимаете, что это клиника. У меня тоже есть аппарат с A4, но я его не включал лет 8, наверное. Я не знаю, что должно произойти, чтобы принудить меня пользоваться этим калькулятором. Если кому-то нравится - ну это их тараканы в голове, Могут легко накатить Android 5 и пользоваться последним Firefox. Причем, там этих Firefox-ов огромный выбор для Android.

@DiD, как давно году эдак в 22ом, максимум в 21ом. последние года 4 гугл на XP - вообще никак звучит как вызов :3 когда и если решусь достать его, дам знать. p.s. согласно в т.ч. и желтой плашке в правом верхнем углу(там где как вернуть активность на ruSO) щас нейронить помоднее будет, и гугления и яндексения и всего остального вместе взятого. могут легко накатить эм... последнее предложение 2го абзаца
